# Get current filename PHP

Tags: php, file, filenames

How do I get just the current file name with PHP?

If I am on URL:

```
website.com/content/content.php
or
website.com/content/content.php?get=get
```

I want to simply get:

```
content.php
```

With nothing more or less then that. But all I have found returns things like:
-"website.com/content/content.php"
-"/content/content.php"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: for once, you can get the whole link name and explode on `/` and use the last value in the array :)

Comment: the keyword you are looking for is `basename`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use:

```
basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])
```

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: For me this returns: C:/Wamp/www/folder/folder/content.php

Comment: Answer updated, please check.

Comment: Thanks, I have to wait a few minutes to "accept the answer".

Comment: Ok, please take your time.

Comment: @user2953063, please select an answer as solution.

Answer (score 6):

You've probably seen:

```
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] // for example: /dir/dir/dir/script.php
```

or

```
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] // as above but not safe
```

---

My favorite:

```
basename(__FILE__) // script.php
```

`basename()` function returns you only filename of script without any dir. You can as well use it with any other input:

```
basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) // outputs: script.php
```

I prefer to avoid `$_SERVER` variables so I use magic variable **__FILE__**

Answer (score 5):

used the `basename`

```
echo basename(__FILE__); //it's return content.php
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php

```
<?php
echo "1) ".basename("/content/content.php", "").PHP_EOL;
echo "2) ".basename("/content/content.php", ".php").PHP_EOL;
echo "3) ".basename("/content/content").PHP_EOL;
echo "4) ".basename("/content/").PHP_EOL;
echo "5) ".basename(".").PHP_EOL;
echo "6) ".basename("/");
?>
//output 
1) content.php
2) content
3) content
4) content
5) .
6)
```

Answer (score -1):

or you can use

`echo __FILE__;`

this is a [magic constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) (click for more info)

This will return the value with .php like you want. Check it!

Comment: this also returns: For me this returns: C:/Wamp/www/folder/folder/content.php

Comment: `__FILE__` itself returns full path from root to current file. Check my answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27296059/3720605)